# Increase maximum locked memory for unprivileged user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I am trying to configure [Ardour3](http://ardour.org/) for Ubuntu Trusty 64. I get the following error:

[image: shot]

I have tried:

1. [root `ulimit`](http://community.ardour.org/node/7876)
2. [editing `limits.conf`](https://community.ardour.org/node/1638)

This is my `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - a user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#        - NOTE: group and wildcard limits are not applied to root.
#          To apply a limit to the root user, <domain> must be
#          the literal username root.
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit (KB)
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#        - chroot - change root to directory (Debian-specific)
#
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
simon        hard   memlock      4096
# End of file
```

Here is some groups data:

[image: groups]

Here's what I got when I tried `ulimit`:

[image: ulimit]

---

EDIT: more file listings.

`/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session - session-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of sessions of *any* kind (both interactive and
# non-interactive).
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required            pam_permit.so
# The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system default in
# /etc/login.defs and user settings, solving the problem of different
# umask settings with different shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.
# See "man pam_umask".
session optional            pam_umask.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional    pam_systemd.so 
session optional            pam_ck_connector.so nox11
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive - session-related modules
# common to all non-interactive services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of all non-interactive sessions.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required            pam_permit.so
# The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system default in
# /etc/login.defs and user settings, solving the problem of different
# umask settings with different shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.
# See "man pam_umask".
session optional            pam_umask.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required    pam_unix.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

---

EDIT1: another file

`/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `login' service
#

# Enforce a minimal delay in case of failure (in microseconds).
# (Replaces the `FAIL_DELAY' setting from login.defs)
# Note that other modules may require another minimal delay. (for example,
# to disable any delay, you should add the nodelay option to pam_unix)
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000

# Outputs an issue file prior to each login prompt (Replaces the
# ISSUE_FILE option from login.defs). Uncomment for use
# auth       required   pam_issue.so issue=/etc/issue

# Disallows root logins except on tty's listed in /etc/securetty
# (Replaces the `CONSOLE' setting from login.defs)
#
# With the default control of this module:
#   [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore user_unknown=bad default=die]
# root will not be prompted for a password on insecure lines.
# if an invalid username is entered, a password is prompted (but login
# will eventually be rejected)
#
# You can change it to a "requisite" module if you think root may mis-type
# her login and should not be prompted for a password in that case. But
# this will leave the system as vulnerable to user enumeration attacks.
#
# You can change it to a "required" module if you think it permits to
# guess valid user names of your system (invalid user names are considered
# as possibly being root on insecure lines), but root passwords may be
# communicated over insecure lines.
auth [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore user_unknown=bad default=die] pam_securetty.so

# Disallows other than root logins when /etc/nologin exists
# (Replaces the `NOLOGINS_FILE' option from login.defs)
auth       requisite  pam_nologin.so

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any 
# lingering context has been cleared. Without out this it is possible 
# that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.
# When the module is present, "required" would be sufficient (When SELinux
# is disabled, this returns success.)
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close

# This module parses environment configuration file(s)
# and also allows you to use an extended config
# file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
# 
# parsing /etc/environment needs "readenv=1"
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
# locale variables are also kept into /etc/default/locale in etch
# reading this file *in addition to /etc/environment* does not hurt
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# This allows certain extra groups to be granted to a user
# based on things like time of day, tty, service, and user.
# Please edit /etc/security/group.conf to fit your needs
# (Replaces the `CONSOLE_GROUPS' option in login.defs)
auth       optional   pam_group.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/time.conf if you need to set
# time restrainst on logins.
# (Replaces the `PORTTIME_CHECKS_ENAB' option from login.defs
# as well as /etc/porttime)
# account    requisite  pam_time.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to
# set access limits.
# (Replaces /etc/login.access file)
# account  required       pam_access.so

# Sets up user limits according to /etc/security/limits.conf
# (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)
session    required   pam_limits.so

# Prints the last login info upon succesful login
# (Replaces the `LASTLOG_ENAB' option from login.defs)
session    optional   pam_lastlog.so

# Prints the message of the day upon succesful login.
# (Replaces the `MOTD_FILE' option in login.defs)
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
session    optional   pam_motd.so

# Prints the status of the user's mailbox upon succesful login
# (Replaces the `MAIL_CHECK_ENAB' option from login.defs). 
#
# This also defines the MAIL environment variable
# However, userdel also needs MAIL_DIR and MAIL_FILE variables
# in /etc/login.defs to make sure that removing a user 
# also removes the user's mail spool file.
# See comments in /etc/login.defs
session    optional   pam_mail.so standard

# Standard Un*x account and session
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-password

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process
# starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are
# intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
# When the module is present, "required" would be sufficient (When SELinux
# is disabled, this returns success.)
```

`/etc/pam.d/lightdm`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

`/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_permit.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

**I changed the contents of `limits.conf` and rebooted. It still doesn't work. This is the new `limits.conf`**:

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - a user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#        - NOTE: group and wildcard limits are not applied to root.
#          To apply a limit to the root user, <domain> must be
#          the literal username root.
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit (KB)
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#        - chroot - change root to directory (Debian-specific)
#
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
simon        hard   memlock      -1
# End of file
```

**How can I increase `simon`'s locked memory limit?**

Comment: May want to look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user as this appears to be a dupe to that.

Comment: @ssnobody Note that my `limits.conf` set a pretty big hard limit. Also, `ulimit -S -l unlimited` does nothing.

Comment: What does the su command recommended to check the limits as root return?

Comment: @ssnobody What did you mean? I'm sorry I couldn't understand that question.

Comment: One of the answers has a comment "to check wether your settings are working for that specific user or not." Have you checked the setting as it describes? What is the result?

Comment: @ssnobody Still not right. http://i.imgur.com/WcFwzmZ.png

Comment: Post your limits.conf , /etc/pam.d/common-session , and /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive

Comment: @ssnobody There you do. `limits.conf` is up top.

Comment: How are you logging in with simon? If you are using normal interactive login, please post /etc/pam.d/login If you are logging in via ssh please post /etc/pam.d/sshd Specifically, we are looking to make sure there is a line that requires pam_limits.so

Comment: @ssnobody I am logging in from the interactive Unity login screen.

Comment: Have you logged out and back in since the change to limits.conf? Post the content of /etc/pam.d/lightdm and /etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin or ensure they have a line requiring pam_limits.so

Comment: @ssnobody There are the files you asked for. I changed limits.conf as the first version and logged in again; it doesn't work. I changed limits.conf to the latest version (updated above), but `ulimit -l` is still 64.

Comment: Note: `ulimits` only changes limits for current shell and its children. `limits.conf` will not affect existing processes. After making change, check using `ulimits -a`, from the shell that you will launch the program from.